# Linux based SMB share: can access only using owner account from Windows

Tags: linux, permissions, samba, smb

In Windows when I connect using test_reader account I can access with no problems. However when I use peter account it gives me Access Denied.

I did some testing and if I change share folder ownership to peter I can access using peter account and then there's no acccess for test_reader. So only a folder owner can access the share.

smb.conf:

```
[share]
        comment = Venice
        path = /media/test_folder/share
        read only = yes
        create mask = 0650
        directory mask = 0760
        browsable = yes
        valid users = @mac
        write list = peter
```

mac memebrs:

```
mac:x:502:test_reader,peter
```

Folder permissions:

```
drwxrw-r-x 2 test_reader mac   2048 Jun  9 18:23 share
```

I have set smbpasswd for each accounts.

Why I cannot access the share using peter account that belongs to the same group as test_reader?

Comment: I believe they may need execute permissions to open the directory.  Which owner has but group does not.

Comment: @Jesse_b you're right, I was missing the x permission

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got `valid users = @mac`, so any member of this group can access the share *as far as SAMBA is concerned*. But you've got `write list = peter` so only `peter` can have a chance of writing to the share.

However, you also need to overlay UNIX file permissions. You have got `drwxrw-r-x 2 test_reader mac`, which allows `test_reader` sufficient access. It does not give any useful access to group `mac` because you're missing the necessary `x` bit in the group directory permission.

In general, if you're using SAMBA to manage access rights I would suggest that you set the filesystem permissions to be `rwxrwxrwx` (`777`). There are exceptions to this, of course, such as when you have users logging in to the server. But for a dedicated fileserver it's a good starting point.